# Grouping strings using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have string like this "7.51B,  8.01B, 7.02E,  7.52E,  8.02E, 
7.01D,  7.51D,  8.01D,  8.54E,  9.04E,  9.54E, 10.04E,  10.54E,  11.04E" . I would like to group this string based on 1B , 2E , 1D , 4E using regex . Any help ?

Example:

Input

```
String s1 = "7.51B, 8.01B, 7.02E, 7.52E, 8.02E, 7.01D, 7.51D, 8.01D, 8.54E, 9.04E, 9.54E, 10.04E, 10.54E, 11.04E"
```

output:

```
1B - 7.51B, 8.01B 
2E - 7.02E, 7.52E, 8.02E 
1D - 7.01D, 7.51D, 8.01D 
4E - 8.54E, 9.04E, 9.54E, 10.04E, 10.54E, 11.04E
```

Comment: Update the post with your attempt

Comment: Also, any particular reason you want to use regex?

Comment: One of my senior suggested using regex reduces the complexity . i m not able to find the pattern to extract the strings . any suggestion is very much welcome .

Comment: No need for regex: split on `", "` then filter four times by last two characters, one for every ending you want, then re-join the four obtained lists and you have your four strings divided by their ending.

Comment: What do you mean `group`, can you show some input and expected output? And if you are new to regex, the best way is read some tutorials and try something first.

Comment: Input 

String s1 = "7.51B, 8.01B, 7.02E, 7.52E, 8.02E, 7.01D, 7.51D, 8.01D, 8.54E, 9.04E, 9.54E, 10.04E, 10.54E, 11.04E"

output:

1B - 7.51B, 8.01B
2E -  7.02E, 7.52E, 8.02E
1D - 7.01D, 7.51D, 8.01D
4E - 8.54E, 9.04E, 9.54E, 10.04E, 10.54E, 11.04E

Comment: I do not think regex is the best way to do this... The comment above shows the right way...

Comment: The only usage for the regex is to capture the last two character and validate them. But what is the problem with this requirements ? Did you tried? IF you don't get the regex, just don't use it first...

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned in the coments above the easiest way is to split and filter by ending. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "7.51B, 8.01B, 7.02E, 7.52E, 8.02E, 7.01D, 7.51D, 8.01D, 8.54E, 9.04E, 9.54E, 10.04E, 10.54E, 11.04E";
    String[] keys = {"1B","2E","1D","4E"};
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for(String k :keys){
        map.put(k, Arrays.stream(s.split(",")).filter(e->e.endsWith(k)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```